# Taking Average of Money in SQL/SQLPro

Tags: ios, sql, macos, sqlite

I am working on a dataset, and I am having trouble trying to calculate the average of a column with dollar currencies in it.  All the values, for example, are listed in the format of $12.00, $5.43, $1,234.00.....

Whenever I use the code below, it returns a value of 0 as the avg.  In the same vein, it does the same thing for the SUM command as well.

```
SELECT AVG(bill_amount) FROM Trips WHERE trip_date >= '08/13/13';
```

Is there something wrong with the code I am using, because I think it's right.

Comment: _is_ there anything in the bill amount column for that date?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, I should have written >= instead of just =.  It should consist of several days.

Comment: what is the database you are using ?

Comment: SQLPro for SQLLite for Mac.

Comment: then please remove the `sql-server` tag. That is for Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Ok it's been removed.  I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: If the column is a text column containing literally "$5.23" then you can't compute a simple sum or average because it isn't a number.  It is like trying to compute the average of "John","Paul","Ringo","George".  The dataset should be set up so that bill_amount is just a number.  Can you change the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to be storing values in the `bill_amount` column as text rather than as a number.  You can convert them to a number and then use average.  Something like this:

```
select avg(cast(case when substr(bill_amount, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then bill_amount
                     else substr(bill_amount, 2)
                end) as decimal(18, 4))
```